# Arranging pyqt combobox in toolbar

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I have made a toolbar in qt designer with a few buttons.  I have found some answers on stack that say you can not add a combobox in qt designer.  With this I found an example of adding it manually.  The method was:

```
self.combo=QtGui.QComboBox(self.toolBar)
self.combo=insertItems(1,["One","Two","Three"])
```

However, this puts the combobox all the way on the left ontop of my other buttons.  How do I add this to the end? I read the doc that says the QComboBox is QStandardItemModel, which either takes self or a parent.  I have tried giving extra arguments like some sort of index but the error says it only takes one argument.  How can I specify which location the combobox will go?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You added QComboBox as a child of QToolbar. It doesn't belong to any layout, so it doesn't take space in toolbar's layout. You need to use `QToolbar::addWidget` or `QToolbar::insertWidget` instead.

```
self.combo=QtGui.QComboBox()
toolBar.addWidget(self.combo)
self.combo.insertItems(1,["One","Two","Three"])
```

Note that I've replaced `=` to `.` in the last line. It should have been typing error.

Comment: awesome thank you.  That is weird that I didnt get any error using = and not .